# Swing - using GridLayout and JList

Tags: java, image, swing, jlist, grid-layout

Apologies for my code being so messy. I've added and changed and commented out a lot of code and haven't gotten round to cleaning any of it up yet.

My main problem is being confused about how to get a 5x5 set of images. I need to be able to update it regularly as it is a map. These updates are going to happen in a separate method from the main and it will be difficult to know what image is in a particular square - hence why I've made an `ArrayList` called previous map.

This is so I can remove the elements of the previous map, then add the new ones. This is really ugly though so I'm trying to change the way I'm doing this by using a `JList`. I don't fully understand it, but it's cropped up in a lot of the examples I've seen.

What I think is happening is that I can add all my 25 images (as `JLabel` components) to this list, then add this list to the panel I want it to show up in.

I'm also trying to use `GridLayout` as that's also shown up in a lot of examples. What I think is happening with grid layout is that I set up a 5x5 grid layout, then use `setLayout(<GridLayout name>)` to the panel I want the grid to be in. I then add the images I want to be in the map to this grid layout.

Is my understanding correct? I've looked at lots of examples and explanations but I'm still unsure. I'm also struggling to understand how I can combine these two ideas - do I have to? If so am I doing it in the right way? If not how would I do this?

So far, I have managed to get this:

[image: Map so far]

However, for some reason,the images are showing up as a column and not in a 5x5 grid.
Here's the relevant code I've been working on:

```
public class GameGUI3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                            
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;                                                                                                         
  JFrame f = new JFrame("Dungeons of Doom");                                                                                                               
  JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();                                                                                                                         
  JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                      
  JPanel moveButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                
  JPanel extraButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                               
  JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                       
  GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(5, 5);                                                                                                                    
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);                                                                                                              
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);                                                                                                      
  DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();                                                                                                     
  JList list = new JList(listModel);                                                                                                                       
  String action;                                                                                                                                           
  ArrayList<String> previousMap = new ArrayList<String>();                                                                                                 
  GridBagConstraints mapC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                      
  private static GUIClient3 client = new GUIClient3();                                                                                                     

  JButton n = new JButton("N");                                                                                                                            
  JButton e = new JButton("E");                                                                                                                            
  JButton s = new JButton("S");                                                                                                                            
  JButton w = new JButton("W");                                                                                                                            
  JButton look = new JButton("LOOK");                                                                                                                      
  JButton pickup = new JButton("PICKUP");                                                                                                                  
  JButton hello = new JButton("HELLO");                                                                                                                    
  JButton quit = new JButton("QUIT");                                                                                                                      

  public GameGUI3()                                                                                                                                        
  {                                                                                                                                                        
      GridBagConstraints northC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                
      GridBagConstraints eastC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                 
      GridBagConstraints southC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                
      GridBagConstraints westC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                 
      GridBagConstraints leftTopC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                              
      GridBagConstraints leftBottomC = new GridBagConstraints(GridBagConstraints extraC = new GridBagConstraints();                                                                                                

      northC.insets = new Insets(10, 65, 10, 10);                                                                                                          
      eastC.insets = new Insets(10, 65, 10, 10);                                                                                                           
      southC.insets = new Insets(10, 65, 10, 10);                                                                                                          
      westC.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10);                                                                                                            
      leftTopC.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 30, 10);                                                                                                        
      mapC.insets = new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30);                                                                                                            
      extraC.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);                                                                                                          

      f.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 600); // (start on x-axis, start on y, width, height)                                                                    

      textPanel.setBounds(1000, 250, 500, 200);                                                                                                            
      textPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));                                                                                                            

      f.getContentPane().add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);                                                                                                

      leftTopC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                  
      leftTopC.gridy = 0;                                                                                                                                  
      leftTopC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;                                                                                               
      leftPanel.add(moveButtonPanel, leftTopC);                                                                                                            

      //mapC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                    
      //mapC.gridy = 1;                                                                                                                                    
      //mapC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;                                                                                                       
      //leftPanel.add(mapPanel, mapC);                                                                                                                     

      //mapPanel.setLayout(gl);                                                                                                                            
      leftPanel.add(mapPanel);                                                                                                                             

      leftBottomC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                               
      leftBottomC.gridy = 2;                                                                                                                               
      leftBottomC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;                                                                                             
      leftPanel.add(extraButtonPanel, leftBottomC);                                                                                                        

      f.getContentPane().add(textPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);                                                                                                

      textArea.setEditable(false);                                                                                                                         

      this.setVisible(false);                                                                                                                              

      northC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                    
      northC.gridy = 0;                                                                                                                                    
      northC.gridwidth = 3;                                                                                                                                
      northC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      moveButtonPanel.add(n, northC);                                                                                                                      

      westC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                     
      westC.gridy = 1;                                                                                                                                     
      westC.gridwidth = 1;                                                                                                                                 
      westC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;                                                                                                              
      moveButtonPanel.add(w, westC);                                                                                                                       

      eastC.gridx = 2;                                                                                                                                     
      eastC.gridy = 1;                                                                                                                                     
      eastC.gridwidth = 3;                                                                                                                                 
      eastC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;                                                                                                              
      moveButtonPanel.add(e, eastC);                                                                                                                       

      southC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                    
      southC.gridy = 2;                                                                                                                                    
      southC.gridwidth = 3;                                                                                                                                
      southC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;                                                                                                            
      moveButtonPanel.add(s, southC);                                                                                                                      

      mapC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                      
      mapC.gridy = 2;                                                                                                                                      
      //mapC.gridwidth = 10;                                                                                                                               
      //mapC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;                                                                                                       
      //mapPanel.setLayout(gl);                                                                                                                            
      leftPanel.add(mapPanel, mapC);                                                                                                                       

      ImageIcon HereBeDragonsIcon = new ImageIcon("HereBeDragons.jpg", "Image");                                                                           
      JLabel HereBeDragonsLabel = new JLabel(HereBeDragonsIcon);                                                                                           

      //mapPanel.add(HereBeDragonsLabel);                                                                                                                  

      int count=0;                                                                                                                                         

      for(int i=0; i<4; i++)                                                                                                                               
      {                                                                                                                                                    
          listModel.add(count++, HereBeDragonsIcon);                                                                                                       
          //listModel.addElement(HereBeDragonsIcon);                                                                                                       

          previousMap.add("HereBeDragonsLabel");                                                                                                           
          //mapPanel.add(HereBeDragonsLabel);                                                                                                              
      }                                                                                                                                                    
      //JList list = new JList(listModel);                                                                                                                 
      //mapPanel.add(list);                                                                                                                                
      mapPanel.add(list);                                                                                                                                  

      extraButtonPanel.add(look, extraC);                                                                                                                  
      extraButtonPanel.add(pickup, extraC);                                                                                                                
      extraButtonPanel.add(hello, extraC);                                                                                                                 
      extraButtonPanel.add(quit, extraC);                                                                                                                  

      n.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                           
      e.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                           
      s.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                           
      w.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                           
      look.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                        
      pickup.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                      
      hello.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                       
      quit.addActionListener(this);                                                                                                                        

      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                                                                                                 
      f.pack();                                                                                                                                            
      f.setVisible(true);                                                                                                                                  
  }
```

Many thanks - if anything is unclear please let me know and I will try and re-phrase my question or explain my code better.

Comment: 1. don't put JLabels to the JList, its DefaultListModel (isn't designated for), 2. JList, JTable, JTree (similair concept) uses Renderer, read for more in Oracle tutorials - How to use List, Tables, Trees, for working code examples, 3. seach here for tons of Q&A with ListCellRenderer + Icon / ImageIcon,

Comment: just about the desing 1.JList should be placed between JButtons for "cursor"  and JTextArea, 2. enlarge the JTextArea from top to the bottom, 3. rest of JButtons would be placed bellow this JTextArea, 4. or to move JButtons for "cursor" below JTextArea

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you, hopefully that's clearer.

Comment: @mKorbel ahh, thank you, I was wondering where was the correct place to write certain bits - it was starting to get very messy and confusing. Thank you.